# Hangfire source code not running on local machine

Tags: .net

I have cloned Hangfire source code from Github for open source contribution, But I couldn't able to run source code on my local machine due to depedencies issue,can anyone guide me how to run hangfire source code on one's local machine. Thnak you in advcance

Try to run hangfire souce code in my local machine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Including the steps you've taken and the error message(s) in your question will make it much easier to answer your question.